# Create special CSS Shape

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

I would like to create a special CSS Shape for my header. The have to look like the first speech bubble from this website http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/ but, the arrow has to be a half circle and the half circle has to be always in the middle. This is for my header so even if the shape is 100% of the browser's length the circle has to stay in the middle of the browser, also when I resize the browser window.

So my question is, is that possible and if so, how?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/f5r9W/

Comment: First i want to say thanks! But you forgot the half circle on the bottom instead of the arrow ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `border-radius: 50%` for the semi-circle, then set the `bottom` to 1/2 of the circle's height, `left: 50%` to center it mostly, and then `margin-left` to negative 1/2 the width:

```
.half-circle {
  background: orange;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.half-circle::after {
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: -10px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
}​
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/a2gPm/1/)

Comment: Glad I could help.  Good luck on the project

Comment: I have one more question ;) Now i would like to add a shadow arround this, but when i do it the circle gets a complete around shadow and not only the half on the bottm. is it possible to make a shadow that really goes just around that shape? Thanks!!!

Comment: Pardon the late response.  Check out this update to the original [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/a2gPm/3/).

Answer (score 0):

The code is right on the page. The one called oval-speech:

HTML:

```
 <div class="oval-speech">test</div>
```

CSS

```
.oval-speech {
position:relative;
width:270px;
padding:50px 40px;
margin:1em auto 50px;
text-align:center;
color:#fff;
background:#5a8f00;
/* css3 */
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#b8db29), to(#5a8f00));
background:-moz-linear-gradient(#b8db29, #5a8f00);
background:-o-linear-gradient(#b8db29, #5a8f00);
background:linear-gradient(#b8db29, #5a8f00);
/*
NOTES:
-webkit-border-radius:220px 120px; // produces oval in safari 4 and chrome 4
-webkit-border-radius:220px / 120px; // produces oval in chrome 4 (again!) but not supported in safari 4
Not correct application of the current spec, therefore, using longhand to avoid future problems with webkit corrects this

-webkit-border-top-left-radius:220px 120px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:220px 120px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:220px 120px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:220px 120px;
-moz-border-radius:220px / 120px;
border-radius:220px / 120px;*/
}

.oval-speech p {font-size:1.25em;}

/* creates part of the curve */
.oval-speech:before {
content:"";
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
bottom:-30px;
right:50%;
height:30px;
border-right:60px solid #5a8f00;
background:#5a8f00; /* need this for webkit - bug in handling of border-radius */
/* css3 */
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:80px 50px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:80px 50px;
border-bottom-right-radius:80px 50px;
/* using translate to avoid undesired appearance in CSS2.1-capabable but CSS3-incapable browsers */
-webkit-transform:translate(0, -2px);
-moz-transform:translate(0, -2px);
-ms-transform:translate(0, -2px);
-o-transform:translate(0, -2px);
transform:translate(0, -2px);
}

/* creates part of the curved pointy bit */
.oval-speech:after {
content:"";
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
bottom:-30px;
right:50%;
width:60px;
height:30px;
background:#fff;
/* css3 */
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:40px 50px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:40px 50px;
border-bottom-right-radius:40px 50px;
/* using translate to avoid undesired appearance in CSS2.1-capabable but CSS3-incapable browsers */
-webkit-transform:translate(-30px, -2px);
-moz-transform:translate(-30px, -2px);
-ms-transform:translate(-30px, -2px);
-o-transform:translate(-30px, -2px);
transform:translate(-30px, -2px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But i need a half circle on the bottom instead of the triangle ;)

Comment: I changed my answer, but you could have just looked a the source. I just copied and pasted what they use in that page you provided.

Comment: Thanks! But this is also wrong, ONLY the small arrow should be a half circle not the whole bubble! Instead of the Arrow on the bottem it must be a half circle. Thanks :)

Comment: Then just remove the border-radius from the oval-speech. I'll change the code above.